# End of script output before headers when trying to open file on Apache [Cloud9IDE]

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I am trying to edit a file using CGI C outside of cgi-bin (~/workspace/files/html) and I tried opening the using this code (edited workspacename and user):

```
pfile = fopen("https://workspacename-user.c9users.io/files/html/output.html", "w");
```

I get an internal server error and when I checked the error logs it showed:

```
[Wed Oct 05 18:40:12.350766 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 28008] [client 10.240.0.213:54468] End of script output before headers: test.cgi, referer: https://workspacename-user.c9users.io/files/html/main.html
```

I tried changing the location of the file that I am trying to open to the cgi-bin directly:

```
pfile = fopen("output.html", "w");
```

and it seemed to work. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You can't `fopen()` a URL in C (maybe you're used to PHP?).  You need to give it a normal file system path.

Comment: "`fopen` accepts paths that are valid on the file system at the point of execution". [Please see `fopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, fopen cannot accept URLs. I tried editing the code to:

```
pfile = fopen("../../../home/ubuntu/workspace/files/html/output.html", "w");
```

and it worked.